# RAII with boost boost::program_options and options_description

Tags: c++, boost, unique-ptr, raii, boost-program-options

Following an example on net [From this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16185997/2805305) I came up with this:

```
int server_port;
auto value_port = new po::typed_value<int>(&server_port); //<-- Really??
value_port->value_name("port");

po::options_description opt_config("Configuation");
opt_config.add_options()("port,P", value_port, "listening port");
```

This apparently works. However explicitly calling `new` to create **raw pointers** in C++ raised alarm bells.

---

So the first thing I tried was to use a **statically allocated object**. (I don’t see the need for dynamically allocated memory here):

```
auto value_port = po::typed_value<int>(&server_port);
value_port.value_name("port");

po::options_description opt_config("Configuation");
opt_config.add_options()("port,P", &value_port, "listening port");
```

This gives a run time error at function exit (when variables are being destructed).
The call stack starts with

- `boost::detail::shared_count::~shared_count() Line 447`

and the error is at

- `boost::checked_delete<boost::program_options::value_semantic const >(const boost::program_options::value_semantic * x) Line 34`

where there is a `delete` instruction.

---

The second thing I tried was to use **`unique_ptr`** (from `std`):

```
auto value_port = make_unique<po::typed_value<int>>(&server_port);
value_port->value_name("port");

po::options_description opt_config("Configuation");
opt_config.add_options()("port,P", value_port.get(), "listening port");
```

The story is similar, with 2 frames this time on the call stack:

- `std::unique_ptr<boost::program_options::typed_value<int,char>,std::default_delete<boost::program_options::typed_value<int,char> > >::~unique_ptr<boost::program_options::typed_value<int,char>,std::default_delete<boost::program_options::typed_value<int,char> > >() Line 1449`
- `std::default_delete<boost::program_options::typed_value<int,char> >::operator()(boost::program_options::typed_value<int,char> * _Ptr) Line 1200`

again at a `delete` instruction.

---

So it seems like `options_description` destructs (the object at) the pointer received via `add_options` and the problem is caused by 2 destructions on the same object.

Shouldn’t this be documented? Doesn’ț this goes against RAII? The caller creates the object, but it is destroyed by another object that at some point receives a pointer to it.
`

---

I used `boost_1_56_0` with `Visual Sudio 2013` running a `debug x64` configuration.

Comment: It's kinda [mentioned](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/doc/html/boost/program_options/option_description.html#boost.program_options.option_descriptionconstruct-copy-destruct) in docs but current design is really ugly. The recommended way is to use po::value<T> that creates po::typed_value<T> via "new" anyway though.

Comment: @frymode it mentions the motivation behind using raw pointers, it does not mention that it takes ownership of the pointer. The only mention of ownership is: `Note: it would be nice to make the second parameter auto_ptr, to explicitly pass ownership.` This statement doesn’t make it clear that it actually takes ownership.

Comment: One of the problem with the boost libraries, is that by maintaining compatibility with C++03, their design can be suboptimal for further versions. In C++11, a `unique_ptr` would be the go-to idiom to express this passing of ownership; in C++03 some people used raw pointers because `auto_ptr` was despised (due to its awkward copy semantics).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you use it is indeed not exactly RAII. unique_ptr is a nice try. What you have to do is to call `release()` instead of `get()`:

```
opt_config.add_options()("port,P", value_port.release(), "listening port");
```